# How to convert this query to CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp

**Here is my `vicidial_log` table `call_date` column look like**

```
+---------------------+
| call_date           |
+---------------------+
| 2016-02-06 03:35:48 |
| 2016-02-06 03:42:38 |
| 2016-02-06 07:38:09 |
| 2016-02-06 07:39:11 |
| 2016-02-06 07:41:09 |
| 2016-02-06 07:42:21 |
| 2016-01-06 07:44:19 |
| 2016-01-06 07:45:28 |
| 2016-01-06 07:47:08 |
| ................... |
+---------------------+
```

I want to group by `call_date` without time.

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT DATE(call_date) AS call_date FROM vicidial_log GROUP BY DATE(call_date);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+---------------------+
| call_date           |
+---------------------+
| 2016-02-06          |
| 2016-01-06          |
| ................... |
+---------------------+
```

> How can I convert this query to CakePHP 3?

Comment: did you try something so far ?

Comment: I solved my problem. I converted my SQL Query to CakePHP 3 custom query builder. Thank you for asking. @ManoharKhadka

Comment: May be you found answer before I posted one..but still you can see and work on that or might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Yes! I fixed already. But your query is also Ok, I approved your answer. @ManoharKhadka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From model :

```
 $query = $this->find();
 $date = $query->func()->DATE([
        'call_date' => 'identifier'
    ]);

 $query->select(['call_date'=>$date])
      ->group(['call_date'=>$date]);  /* or simply ->group($date) */
```

From Controller :

```
 $query = $this->your_table_name->find();
 $date = $query->func()->DATE([
        'call_date' => 'identifier'
    ]);

 $query->select(['call_date'=>$date])
      ->group(['call_date'=>$date]); /* or simply ->group($date) */
```

For results :

```
 $query->toArray(); 
 /* or */
 $query->all();
```

Comment: To sum it up: It should be put into the model layer and then called from the controller layer: `$this->VicidialLogs->findCallDatesGroupedByCallDate($date)->all()` etc. Model queries should not be terminated to allow reuse.

Answer (score 1):

> I fixed my problem by using below query.

**IN CONTROLLER :**

```
$query = $this->VicidialLog->find()
        ->select(['call_date' => 'DATE(call_date)'])
        ->where([/*Here is some conditions*/])
        ->group(['call_date'=>'DATE(call_date)']);
```